# Amazon S3 php SDK getBucketPolicy returns empty

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the amazon s3 sdk and the getBucketPolicy call does not seem to return anything for me has anyone else had a similar issue.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getBucketPolicy

If i run.

```
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key'    => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret'
    ));
    $result = $client->getBucketPolicy(array(
        // Bucket is required
        'Bucket' => 'bucket',
    ));
    print_r($result->toArray());
```

it returns

```
Policy {}
```

But when i view properties with the Amazon s3 console, on my bucket and click edit policy it is.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy123456789",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    } 
  ]
}
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I found it! It was so simple... Yet so hard... Since I couldn't find it in the docs.

The response you get when you execute:

```php
$response = $this->S3Client
    ->getBucketPolicy(['Bucket' => $bucketName])
    ->get('Policy');
```

Is an object of type: `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream`

You have to get the context of the stream using the `getContents()` method:

```php
$response = $this->S3Client
    ->getBucketPolicy(['Bucket' => $bucketName])
    ->get('Policy')
    ->getContents();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have IAM policy configured or stored credetials at .aws/config?

If you use code without credentials provided as

```
$result = $client->getBucketPolicy(array(
    // Bucket is required
    'Bucket' => 'bucket',
));
```

It supposes either IAM policy is configured at AWS console for your instance or you stored your credentials to ~/.aws/config

If you don't have any, so you should pass configuration as

```
$result = $client->getBucketPolicy(array(
    // Bucket is required
    'Bucket' => 'bucket',
    'key' => 'put your key',
    'secret' => 'put your secret',
    'region' => 'put your region',
));
```

Comment: Hi evgeniy i have updated my question i am calling the code correctly give it a go add a policy to your bucket and run the above code on your bucket with a policy added and see if it returns the json policy, thanks

Comment: If the credentials are not present, you get an exception.